# A driver appdrv.01.sys cannot load

Tags: windows

I'm dealing with an issue which is causing me a headache.

All of a sudden I see the below screen popping up every time I start windows.

[image]

I have not uninstalled any programs for many months.

I looked all over the Windows Event Viewer but none of the logs seem to refer to appdrv01.

Per Google appdrv01.sys is not a Microsoft Windows driver.

Is there any way I find what app is using/invoking it so I can uninstall it?

Per Google, this driver should reside in Windows/System32 but I don't see it there.

I was thinking of using Process Explorer, but since appdrv is missing on my computer that option does not seem to be useful.

As a workaround, I backed up the registry and deleted all entries in the registry referring to appdrv01. The issue seems to be fixed.

I am still curious to know if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: This is an unknown file. It should reside in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers`. If you can find it there, see in its Properties which is the company that created it. It would have been useful to list the registry keys that you deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I could not find it in C:\Windows\System32\drivers either.

Comment: Again you are correct, I was way too fast and deleted the registry backup file without paying attention to the keys. Maybe the registry entry should tell me what software is using appdrv01.sys

Comment: You may be able to find them in the registry backup.